# Immitate two lists from single list

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list:

```
<ul>
    <li class="title">title1</li>
    <li>elem1</li>
    <li>elem2</li>
    <li>elem3</li>
    <li class="title">title2</li>
    <li>elem1</li>
    <li>elem2</li>
    <li>elem3</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to display this list where the titles will be located in the top of the list. Something like the result of:

```
<ul style="float:left;">
    <li>title1</li>
    <li>elem1</li>
    <li>elem2</li>
    <li>elem3</li>
</ul>
<ul style="float:left;">
    <li>title2</li>
    <li>elem1</li>
    <li>elem2</li>
    <li>elem3</li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that I cannot change the original html and I have to do it using css only.
Is such thing possible? How can I do it?

Here is the two lists - the original and the desired style: http://jsfiddle.net/MNYnW/2/

Comment: Your 2 lists look exactly the same, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/MNYnW/) as you have them in your question (there is no CSS) ... what do you want it to look like ?

Comment: css only? no javascript?

Comment: AFAIK, CSS works with existing DOM, it does not create DOM elements as per your requirement of splitting a UL into 2 ULs

Comment: Is this what how you want your lists to look : http://jsfiddle.net/MNYnW/1/ ?

Comment: please show your outcome what you want to achieve

Comment: @Th0rndike: Css only - no javascript

Comment: @ManseUK: You right, thanks for not me! - I updated the question.

Comment: @gabitzish: Yes. Thanks. Do you have any idea how to do in in the original list using css only?

Comment: @Th0rndike: I don't see how you make the original list to look like the second list.

Comment: @Naor yeah that comment was before your edit, so i wasn't getting the question right

Answer (score 5):

May you can achieve with css3 `cloumn-count` property. Write like this:

**CSS**

```
.list {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 5px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 5px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>title1</li>
    <li>elem1</li>
    <li>elem2</li>
    <li>elem3</li>
    <li>title2</li>
    <li>elem1</li>
    <li>elem2</li>
    <li>elem3</li>
</ul>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/MNYnW/16/

Comment: great solution! Moved to tears T_T

Comment: It's nice solution but it's useful only if you do have equal li for example 4 and 4 in this case. If you try to add one more li your layout will got break. Also you can't add dynamically more title in that case

Comment: @tarun my answer is depend on the OP question  which is "Immitate two lists from single list with only css" & my answer yes. If he asked the list are dynamic or something else then may be my answer is different from that depending upon the question.

Comment: @tarun check this jsfiddle.net/MNYnW/23/ if you add one more li. you have play with the css.

Answer (score 0):

If you need cross browser fully dynamic solution you can do it by jQuery below:

```
$(function() {

    var previousList = $('#list').html().split(/title[0-9]+/);  
    var newList = '';   
    var i = 1;

    $('#list > li').each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        var title = /title[0-9]+/.test(self.text());

        if(!(self.index() == 0)) {
            if(title) {
                newList += '</ul><ul style="float: left;"><li>' + self.html() + previousList[i].substring(0, previousList[i].length - 4);
                i++;
            }
        }

        else {
            if(title) {
                 newList += '<ul style="float: left;"><li>' + self.html() + previousList[i].substring(0, previousList[i].length - 4);
                 i++;           
            }
        }        

    }); 

    newList += '</ul>';

    $('body').html(newList);
});
```

Comment: The question isn't even tagged as javascript, let alone jQuery and OP has specifically said no script...

Comment: I know But it's cant be achieve by CSS in dynamic situation in all browsers. Because there many be one title may be five title. May be 10 <li> on first may be 100 <li> on second. So you can't fix it by CSS.

Comment: @Tarun: I don't find this issue "dynamic". I need each li defined by title class to be in another column.